# Trying to send an image from the local file system to a Discord channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am stuck working out why images are not going through on the `message.send()` call.

I am able to get the text, but nothing else. Channel permissions are correct, as currently the bot has `Administrator` permissions.

This is the code to get my bot send an image on `!random` command:

```js
  client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
      if (msg.content === '!random') {
        // Find the channel with the specified name
        const channel = client.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'mod-default-log');
  
        console.log('Channel:', channel); // log the channel object
  
        try {
          // Declare the attachment as a collection
          const attachment = new Collection([{
            file: fs.readFileSync('./images/1b509fe1549a1c08861ebc00dd39b68ec29c2758.png'),
            name: 'image.png'
          }]);
  
          console.log('Attachment:', attachment); // log the attachment object
  
          // Send the message with the attachment
          channel.send('This is a message with a file attachment from a URL!', attachment);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error.message); // log error message
        }
      }
  });
```

This is my `Intents` defining:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    
]});
```

I have enabled debugging to try and work out why am I unable to get my bot send images.

When trying to pass the collection the debugging returns this is the result:

```
Attachment: Collection(1) [Map] { undefined => undefined }
```